# How to get Google to crawl our product pages as soon as they are updated for in-stock or out-of-stock?

Tags: googlebot, sitemap, crawl-rate

We have an automobile website where we have different cars and bike models. We have product pages for every car/bike. Each page has the products price, Offers, reviews , news, images and videos.

There are few problems which we are facing:

1. If a new offer is launched, the Google crawls our website too late and hence we are not able to show the offers in the title or description of Google results.
2. Similarly if product gets discontinued, Google shows it as active in title and description while once user comes to our website, it is shown as a discontinued product.

Same is the case if we add any new image, news or reviews.

How can we instantly ask Google to recrawl if our product page is updated? We have thousands of product pages so anything manual would be not scalable

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you can't force Google to crawl your site any faster.

Why not add 301 redirects to those discontinued products to something comparable instead?

Temporary promotional text on title tags is not likely a good SEO approach when the crawl rate can't be prioritized to keep Google's indexes of your site up to date in real-time.

If you must control how your products are presented on SERPs in real-time there's always AdWords. It would give you complete control over the messaging and scheduling of your promotions.

Comment: Google ignores the `changefreq` and `lastmod` in sitemaps because they have found them to be widely misused and unreliable.  See https://www.seroundtable.com/google-priority-change-frequency-xml-sitemap-20273.html

Comment: True. Changing my answer